# java eclipse, boolean value goes wrong

Tags: java, eclipse, boolean

I got two threads running on Main.java and a boolean field Main.bool which is false in the beginning.
The first thread will set Main.bool to true.
**After that**, The second thread will print out Main.bool. And the result is **FALSE**.

More interesting, I tried to print out a random text before printing Main.bool, then the result turned out to be correct(true).

Anyone have an idea what is going on here? I'm using eclipse Kepler.

```
Main.bool = false;
thread1.setBool(true);
// then wait for some seconds
// case 1
thread2.printBool(); --> false
// case 2
System.out.println("blah blah");
thread2.printBool(); --> true
```

Comment: Make your field `volatile`.

Comment: When you dealing with multithreading use volatile field to make it synchornized

Comment: When you have multiple threads, there is no guarantee to the ordering in which the threads execute. They will rotate in execution in an arbitrary manner. Therefore, it's possible that thread2 prints out the boolean before thread1 changes the value.

Comment: no it's not, I made sure that thread1 happened before thread2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your filed 'bool' as volatile.

**Any write to a volatile variable establishes a happens-before relationship with subsequent reads of that same variable**

For more [info](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html).

Note: Making a field volatile, ensures that anyone who is reading the value of that field reads it from the memory and not from the local copy.

Comment: yes thank you, I do know about volatile field, I just don't understand why it happened that way, and yours seems to be the right answer:)